# Создать пары элементов по разным признакам

Tags: python, алгоритм

У нас есть массив людей. У каждого человека есть признаки (пол, возраст, рост, работа, т.д.). Нам нужно создать пары людей с максимально разными признаками.
На выходе мы получаем пары фамилии (даётся в признаках), которые подходят условию.

Мне не обязательно нужна программа, мне нужен алгоритм, что бы понять, как это работает. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Нужен критерий максимального различия признаков.

Comment: @becouse Давай пока просто абсолютно разные. То есть не было одинаковых признаками. Максимально разные - это все признаки отличается (если возраст 9 и 10, то это уже разные).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример когда близость подразумевает различие по всем компонентам (мера Хемминга)

```
person={"A":[1,23,12,23,12],"B":[0,12,12,23,12],"C":[0,24,11,21,13]}


def intersection(a, b):
    c = [value for value in a if value in b]
    return c

def isDifferent(a,b):
    if len(intersection(a,b))==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

keys=list(person.keys())

for key1 in range(len(keys)):
    for key2 in range(key1+1,len(keys)):
        if isDifferent(person[keys[key1]],person[keys[key2]]):
            print(keys[key1],keys[key2])
```

Вот пример с максимальной косинусовой мерой блилости

```
import math

person={"A":[1,23,12,23,12],"B":[0,12,12,23,12],"C":[0,24,11,21,13]}


def scalar(a,b):
    temp = 0;
    for i in range(len(a)):
        temp =temp+a[i]*b[i]
    return temp;
def measure(a,b):
    return scalar(a,b)/(math.sqrt(scalar(a,a))*math.sqrt(scalar(b,b)))

keys=list(person.keys())

for key1 in range(len(keys)):
    zmax=-2;
    pmax=key1
    for key2 in range(key1+1,len(keys)):
        zcos=measure(person[keys[key1]],person[keys[key2]])
        if zcos>zmax:
            pmax=key2
    if pmax!=key1:
        print(keys[key1], keys[pmax])
```

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм следующий.

1. Для каждого признака вводится мера близости. Например, для возраста (признак измеренный в шкале интервалов) это может быть разность возрастов, взятая по абсолютной величине. Для работы (признак измеренный в номинальной шкале) -  совпадение/несовпадение. Для других признаков - аналогично.
2. На основе введенных определений вводится мера близости в многомерном пространстве признаков. Вводится либо формально, путем аналитического задания обобщающей метрики, либо путем применения методов многомерного шкалирования.
3. После этого рассчитываются  взаимные расстояниям между всеми парами объектов. В кластерном анализе  и метрических алгоритмах  классификации обычно интересуются наименьшими расстояниями. А вам очевидно наоборот, среди всех пар следует искать  такие, у которых расстояние в пространстве признаков с введенными мерами оказались наибольшими.